# How efficient are MongoDB projections?

Tags: mongodb, projection

Is there a lot of overhead in excluding nearly all of the data in a document when querying a mongo database?

For example, in the case where I only want **field1** and **field2**, for a collection with a document structure of:

```
{
    "field1" : 1
    "field2" : true
    "field3" : ["big","array",...]
    "field4" : ["another","big","array",...]
}
```

would I benefit more from:

1. Creating a separate collection alongside this collection containing
   only field1 and field2, or
2. Using .find() on the original documents with inclusion/exclusion parameters

Note: The inefficiency of saving the same data twice isn't a concern for me as much as the efficiency of querying the data

Many thanks!

Comment: how big are these documents?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Around 0.3MB each, and field1 and field2 combined <1kB. Would the document size have an effect?

Comment: it makes a difference in how much RAM the documents take up since when you query a document the entire document may end up in RAM even if you only want some specific fields.   Are the two fields you want always the first two fields?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Yes, always the first 2 fields, and their combined size is always much less than the size of the whole document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Projection is somewhat similar to using column names explicitly in SQL, so it seems a little counter-intuitive to ask if returning smaller amount of data would incur overhead over returning larger amount of data (full document).

So you have to find the document (depending on how you .find() it may be fast or slow) but returning only first two fields of the document rather than all the fields (complete document) would make it *faster* not slower.

Having a second collection may only benefit if you are concerned about your collection fitting into RAM.  If the documents in the duplicate collection are much smaller then they can presumably fit into a smaller amount of total RAM decreasing a chance that a page will need to be swapped in from disk.  However, if you are writing to this collection as well as original collection then you have to have a lot more data in RAM than if you just have the original collection.

So while the intricate details may depend on your individual set-up, the general answer would probably be 2. you will benefit more from using projection and only returning the two fields you need.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed answer! A further question, if I index over field1 and field2 and query for a subset of the collection on these 2 fields, will this only load that subset of data into the RAM?

Apologies for my lack of knowledge on databases.

Comment: only the pages that contain the documents you need will be loaded into RAM.  Of course the index will be in RAM also.

Comment: Are you really sure about this answer? MongoDB stores entire documents, not columns, so having to filter out the unwanted fields seems like an extra operation that will slow down the query (With the exception of covered queries).

Comment: Yes, I’m pretty sure about the answer.